# Django Oauth Toolkit as SSO server

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-oauth-toolkit

I want to know can we use Django oauth Toolkit (DOT) as SSO server?

I am using Django Rest Framework in backend.

Steps I need to achieve :

1. On clicking the Login Button in the client server, it redirects to the server asking to authorise.
2. If already logged in it will return the auth code.
3. If not logged in open the log in prompt.
4. On successful login step 2 will followed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [DOT supports OpenID Connect](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oidc.html) so you can set it up as an SSO server.

Once [configured](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html), your server should have the `o/authorize` endpoint where you can redirect your clients when logging in. DOT will handle the authorization request for you (step 2-4).

With the authorization code, DOT also provides the `o/token` endpoint for access and id tokens request as well.